# Split sentences to words and count the number of characters 'a' in each word

Tags: matlab

I need to input sentences with upper letter, then split sentences to words and for each word count number of character 'a'

I've made this

```
clear
sentences=input('Write your sentences: ','s');
low=lower(sentences);
disp('Sentences splitted to words: ');
words=regexp(low,' ','split');
for i=1:length(words)
    disp(words(i))
end
```

And now I don't know how to count the character 'a' in each of words after splitting because these words are converted to cell.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Start here in the documentation: [Characters and Strings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html)

Comment: There is no need to artificially insert a tag in the title; ideally, a title should be a coherent sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process each cell, use [`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with an [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) that counts the number of times `'a'` occurs in each word:

```
count = cellfun(@(w) sum(w=='a'), words);
```

You could equivalently use a loop:

```
N = numel(words);
count = NaN(1,N); %// preallocate for speed
for n = 1:N
    w = words{n};
    count(n) = sum(w=='a');
end
```

Comment: `w=='a'` is a generally bad practice for strings (unless one performs a bunch of input validation). `strfind` would probably be a better option: `count = cellfun('length',strfind(words,'a'))`.

Comment: It would be bad practice to test two strings for equality using `==` (they may have different lengths), but I don't think it's bad practice to compare a string with a _character_. Or am I missing something?